# Numpy using where with varying array sizes

Tags: python, numpy

So I have two PIL images of RGBA. What I want to do is find all locations where the RGB values are the same and alpha is 255. It looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img1 = np.array(Image.open(/path/to/img1).convert('RGBA'), float).reshape(32,32,4)
img2 = np.array(Image.open(/path/to/img2).convert('RGBA'), float).reshape(32,32,4)

# Checks to see if RGB of img1 == RGB of img2 in all locations that A=255
np.where((img1[:,:,:-1] == img2[:,:,:-1]) &\ # RGB check
         (img1[:,:,3] == 255)) # Alpha check
```

But this results in `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (32,32,3) (32,32)`.
I didn't think I was trying to broadcast them together, I just wanted to find the indeces, which I guess in turn broadcasts them in this statement. Is there another way to do this, or a way to not broadcast unequal shapes?

Comment: `img1[:, :, :-1]` results in an array of shape `32, 32, 3`.  `img1[:, :, 3]` results in an array of shape `32, 32`.

Comment: @mgilson yes I know. But is what I'm trying to accomplish clear? I thought the above would work because I thought `np.where` would allow for multiple "where" statements, not broadcast them together

Comment: And, to point out a bit of style, the `\ ` for line continuation is unnecessary here.  Python concatenates lines that are in unenclosed braces, brackets or parenthesis (as is the case here).  In fact, PEP 8 (the "official" style guide) recommends using parenthesis to continue lines and _never_ using the `\ ` for line continuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.all(axis=-1)` to find locations where all three RGB values are equal:

```
np.where((img1[..., :-1] == img2[..., :-1]).all(axis=-1) 
         & (img1[..., 3] == 255))
```

---

As [mgilson points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354171/numpy-using-where-with-varying-array-sizes/37354408#comment62223831_37354171),  `(img1[..., :-1] == img2[..., :-1])` has shape `(32, 32, 3)`. Calling `.all(axis-1)` reduces the last axis to a scalar boolean value, so

```
(img1[..., :-1] == img2[..., :-1]).all(axis=-1)
```

has shape `(32, 32)`. This matches the shape of `(img1[..., 3] == 255)`, so these boolean arrays can be combined with the [bitwise-and operator, `&`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html).

Comment: +1 I think the reduction along the last axis is what OP is asking for.  I wonder if OP wants to make sure that the alpha values are the same too ... (In which case it simplifies to `(img1 == img2).all(axis=-1)` without the ellipsis)

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I wanted. And yes @mgilson I was able to add yours too to get the alpha check. Thanks!

Comment: I'll also point out that `&` is _not_ the logical-and operator (though it's frequently used as such).  It's the _binary_ `&` operator which is special cased to return an array of logicals if both the right-hand and left-hand sides are logical arrays.  For _logical_ and, I've always recommended using `np.logical_and` (which doesn't have the precedence issues that the `&` operator has that sometimes bite people trying to use it)...